# Subscribe to changes in mail folder and all it's subfolders using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

My **Inbox** folder has the following structure:

```
Inbox
 >>Subfolder1
 >>Subfolder2
 ..
 >>SubfolderN
```

I expected that when I subscribe notifications will be received for all messages, including messages in the subfolders of the **Inbox**:

```
{
  "changeType": "created",
  "notificationUrl": "https://webhookurl",
  "resource": "/users/{id}/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-04-03T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

But notifications come only for the parent **Inbox** folder.

> How can I specify in a subscription to receive notifications for subfolders too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to receive notification for all messages, you should use the resource path: [/users/{id}/messages](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks.md#use-the-microsoft-graph-api-to-get-change-notifications). This should provide notification for all messages in a user's mailbox.

Comment: In this case I'll receive messages in all folders, including for example Spam and Sent items.

Comment: You're correct. However, the currently [supported resource paths(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) are a regular folder or top-level entity collection of messages, events, contacts, or tasks.

Comment: You may also voice your feedback for this on https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests